# .NET MAC algorithms and implementing ISO 9797 MAC algorithm 1

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I need to implement ISO 9797 MAC algorithm 1 in .NET. Before writing the code I want to understand the concepts so that there's no misunderstandings (thus pardon me if some of the questions are just "is that correct").

Firsty, in [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9797-1#cite_note-2) it is said that:

> Algorithm 1 is commonly known as CBC-MAC

**Question 1:** My reference mentions MAC algorithms at two points - in one place it mentions it as ISO 9797 MAC algorithm 1 (DES) and in the other it mentions CBC-MAC (AES). From what I understand these should be the same CBC-MAC, one with DES and the other with AES, is that right? Are the terms just interchangeably used in my reference?

**Question 2:** Is it correct that CBC-MAC works the same as CBC mode of operation? From what I see the algorithms are identical - you take an input, you XOR it and then encrypt it with key and so on.

**Question 3**: If I use DES and my above reasoning is correct, is this the same as ANSI X9.9? My reference is not very clear on this one, but this is what I gathered after looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Yes, those should be the same. That also means that for DES only single DES is used to protect the MAC. This is insecure due to the key size used.

Q2: Yes, that's why it is called CBC-MAC, the difference is that the output consists of the only the last "ciphertext" block or part of the last block. This in turn means that combining this with a cipher mode that is using the same key is insecure, and that the MAC is vulnerable if dynamically sized messages are used. Beware that CBC-MAC generally uses bit padding or ISO padding (a byte valued 0x80 followed by 0-7 bytes valued 0x00 for DES), not PKCS#5 or PKCS#7 padding.

Q3: ANSI X9.9 seems to describe CBC-MAC where the output size is only 4 bytes. A description and picture can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/linuxonibm/com.ibm.linux.z.wskc.doc/wskc_c_emvmac.html#l0wskc02_emvmac__l0wskc02_fig21).

---

For AES a better mode of MAC has been written to allow dynamically sized messages called AES-CMAC or OMAC. It consists of an initial and final calculation, while using standard CBC-MAC in the middle.